# How to use intent filter to open myapp(an Activity but not MainActivity) from other app's URL(may be message) with starting my app individual

Tags: android, android-intent

As title:
How to use intent filter to open myapp(an Activity but not MainActivity) from other app's URL(may be a message) with starting my app individually (that's mean myapp is not starting inside the other app which included the URL)

I have developed myapp with sharing function by using intent filter. Although I can display the URL in certain activity of myapp, myapp is started inside the other app(like myapp occupy the other app for operation).

below is my code:

AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.URLActivity"
        android:label="@string/URL_details"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="123.456.789.10" android:scheme="https"></data>
            />
        </intent-filter>


       </activity>
```

open URL's Activity's Fragment's code:

```
Intent intentFromURL = getActivity().getIntent();

    if (intentFromURL.getDataString()!=null) {
        mIntentURL = intentFromURL.getDataString();
        String[] splittingURL = mIntentURL.split("/");
        mProductCode = splittingURL[5];
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to start myapp inside the other app. Also, I can't find such case and don't know need to search which key word...please help me to solve it, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can open url in my Activity on myapp rather than "allowing other app open my apps' Activity".

For my case, I add a code to AndroidManifest.xml under the activity I want to call.

the solution as below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.URLActivity"
    android:label="@string/URL_details"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="123.456.789.10" android:scheme="https"></data>
        />
    </intent-filter>


   </activity>
```

I added "android:launchMode="singleTask"", the task will launch on my app but not other app.(etc. Whatsapp)

I hope this can help ppl like me=]